# Get filename after uploading with Dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload images with Dropzone js and PHP, it works but I would like to save the file upload name in a PHP variable and it's failed.

form.php

```
<form method="post" action="new_is_add.php" id="form_first" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone">
            <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
                <span>
                    Max 2 files
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="submit_new" id="submit_new" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropzone.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
var theDate = new Date().getTime();
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#my-dropzone", {
    paramName: "file",
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    maxFiles: 2,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    renameFilename: function (filename) {
        return theDate + '_' + filename;
    },
    url: "new_is_add.php",                      
    autoProcessQueue: false,
});

$('#submit_new').click(function(){           
  myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

new_is_add.php

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile);
    echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
}
```

My `$_FILES['file']['name']` is empty, how can I get the filename?

Comment: Is `$_FILES['file']['name']` an array? You have the option to upload more than one file, so I think there might be an array of files `$_FILES['file']['name'][0]` and `$_FILES['file']['name'][1]`. Same goes for `tmp_name`.

I've never used dropzone before, so I'm not positive, hence the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Your right I can upload more than one file, for the moment I try with one. I tried `$_FILES['file']['name'][0]` and `tmp_name` but same problem

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES)` cheers

Comment: It returns `array(0) { }`, it's strange because my image is correctly upload in /uploads/